# air datepicker change css

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, sass

This is the link about Air Datepicker

http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/

And then, This is the github page about this datepicker.

https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker

Could you answer me to change some css style?
I would like to change some parts of color, especially years and months are in a top part from red to blue.

I can't find to change css code in wiki which is for Air Datepicker.
Thank you very much.

Comment: https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/blob/master/dist/css/datepicker.css

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the project on github and customize sass files as you want.

Location of sass files here:
https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker/tree/master/src/sass

`_datepicker-config.scss` and `cell.scss` files allow Sass customizing

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke it as:

```
new AirDatepicker("#id", {inline: true})
```

The 'picker will stay on a screen and then you can explore any CSS via devtools.